# Delete some rows of a CSV, in-place

Tags: python, csv

This:

```
import csv
with open('original.csv', 'rb') as inp, open('new.csv', 'wb') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        if row[2] != "0":
            writer.writerow(row)
os.remove('original.csv')
os.rename('new.csv', 'original.csv')
```

allows to delete certain rows of a CSV.

**Is there a more pythonic way to delete some rows of a CSV file, in-place?** (instead of creating a file, deleting the original, renaming, etc.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't a more Pythonic way: you can't delete stuff in the middle of a file.  Write out a new file with the stuff you want, and then rename it.

Comment: You could also read from a file, close it, make the necessary changes, then overwrite the file with the changes.

Comment: @AndrewLamarra can you post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that your code does not import the os module, even though you're using it. Regardless, here's a method of doing what you need it to do without using that module.

This will open in read mode first to get the data, then write mode to overwrite. Note that you need to pass the `csv.reader(f)` statement to the list() function or else the data variable will simply point to the memory address of the CSV file and you won't be able to do anything with the content once it's closed. list() will actually copy the information for you.

```
import csv

with open("original.csv", "rb") as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f))

with open("original.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in data:
        if row[2] != "0":
            writer.writerow(row)
```